# How to use admin REST API in Xamarin application to create new users in couchbase sync gateway?

Tags: authentication, xamarin, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am creating a xamarin mobile application and I want to create new users from the mobile application , I know I can create users from sync gateway configuration or from admin REST API ,
I tried to use the admin REST API in the application but I got Java.Net.SocketTimeoutException

so how can I use the admin REST API to create users in the application ?

Here in the code I am using :

```
        private async void CreateUserBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(); //Creating a new instance of HttpClient. (Microsoft.Net.Http)
        content = "{\"Username\":\"user.com\",\"Password\":\"123456\"}";
        string url = "http://<server_ip>:4985/user/";
        var request = await _client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    }
```

Comment: what is "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" for?

Comment: Are you sure port 4985 is accessible from the Xamarin app? Also, I'm assuming the username, password, and server_ip in this example are not what you are actually using?

Comment: @MatthewGroves I have edited my question , no I am not sure that port 4985 is accessible from the Xamarin app , but I should use it to create a new user and I don't know what is its alternative , I have hidden the server_ip in the question for security reasons

Answer (score 2):

In Sync Gateway, port 4985 is intentionally not public by default. Opening it allows anybody full access to your data.

1. Integrate with a third-party authentication provider using OpenID Connect. You can configure these to create users on-demand when they sign in.
   https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/current/authentication.html#openid-connect
2. Write your own small service that can take new user requests from your app, which then calls out to a firewalled Sync Gateway Admin API.
   https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/current/authentication.html#custom-authentication

Comment: "create service that can take new user requests from your app" => can you please more explain this part , Thanks .

Comment: @MariaNabil This [blog](https://blog.couchbase.com/custom-authentication-with-couchbase-mobile/) discusses the custom authentication option with example